# Script to open Safari > Preferences > Websites > Notifications

Tags: macos, applescript, safari, automation

I do not believe that macOS PPPC on Ventura and higher will permit this, but:

Is there a way to use AppleScript (osascript) to open Safari's Preferences window and change focus to Websites > Notifications?

Other web browsers can be easily scripted to show the notifications section of their settings, ie: `$ open -a "Google Chrome" chrome://settings/content/notifications`

This would be useful to assist an end user with disabling problematic/fake notifications.

Comment: Have you tried UI scripting?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this following AppleScript on macOS 14.1.

I think this is as close as you will be able to get with code. However, I was not able to select "Notifications"

```
if application "Safari" is running then
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "," using {command down} -- opens Safari Settings window
        repeat until button "Websites" of toolbar 1 of front window exists
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click button "Websites" of toolbar 1 of window (get title of front window)
    end tell
end if
```